# How to get complete ddl script for stored procedure in Amazon Redshift without knowing the procedure arguments

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

I want it to be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_sp1
    (f1 integer, f2 character varying(20)) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS 
    $$ DECLARE min_val int; 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tbl; 

    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl(id int); 

    INSERT INTO tmp_tbl 
    VALUES (f1), (10001), (10002); 

    SELECT INTO min_val MIN(id) 
    FROM tmp_tbl; 

    RAISE INFO 'min_val = %, f2 = %', min_val, f2; 
END;  
$$
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Redshift or Snowflake? Choose only one to tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the source directly from `pg_proc`.

```sql
SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'sp_example';
--                               prosrc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_example(arg1 character varying(512)…
```

Alternatively, using `psql`, you can list all functions and procedures with `\df`, which shows the argument data types

```sql
\df
-- schema |    name    | result data type  | argument data types | type
----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+------
-- public | f_example  | character varying | integer             | func
-- public | sp_example | -                 | character varying   | func
```

Then you can use `SHOW PROCEDURE` to get the full DDL.

```sql
SHOW PROCEDURE sp_example ( character varying );
--                     Stored Procedure Definition
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_example(arg1 character varying(512)…
```

Comment: i used the first method in redshift but it is displaying starting from declare...like this  DECLARE x int := 3; y int := 4; BEGIN DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_tbl; CREATE TEMP TABLE test_tbl(a int, b varchar(256)); CALL inner_proc(x, multiplier, y); insert into test_tbl values (x, y::varchar); END.....but i also wanted create procedure statement as well..Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your query tool and the type of "dollar quoting" used in the procedure. Try using a different tool. You can get `psql` on a Mac by running `brew install postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the trick and works for me:

```
SELECT 'CREATE PROCEDURE ' + n.nspname + '.' + p.proname + '()  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ ' 
AS PROCEDURE_NAME, p.prosrc AS DDL, ' $$ ' AS PROCEDURE_END
     FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n, pg_catalog.pg_proc_info p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d ON (p.prooid=d.objoid)
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c ON (d.classoid=c.oid AND c.relname='pg_proc')
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace pn ON (c.relnamespace=pn.oid AND pn.nspname='pg_catalog')
     WHERE p.pronamespace=n.oid
     AND p.prokind='p';
```